# To automatically select the name of a <select> option selected in HTML when the relevant page is loaded in the <select> option

Tags: javascript, html

When I select an option in the `<select>` element in HTML, when the relevant page loads, I want to show the name of this page in the `<select>` element. This way I can see which page I'm on in the `<select>` section. How can I achieve this?

```
select id="select_page">
            <option value="Page1.html">Page 1</option>
            <option value="Page2.html">Page 2</option>
            <option value="Page3.html">Page 3</option>
            <option value="Page4.html">Page 4</option>
</select>
```

Here, when I select the 2nd page from the options,  should show it as "page 2".

```
const selPage = document.getElementById("select_page");

 sayfaSecim.addEventListener("change", () => {
    const selectedValue = sayfaSecim.value;
    
  window.location.href = selectedValue;
  });
```

I tried this code. When I select the option in `<select>`, the required page loads correctly, but the `<select>` section automatically sets the first directory.

Comment: Look into using the selected attribute.

Comment: thank you very much. I researched and did it thanks to your suggestion.